# Clojurescript dead-code elimination apparently not working

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-compiler, dead-code, shadow-cljs

I have a ClojureScript project with the following barebone frontend app (`main` being the entry point):

```
(ns shadowman.app
  (:require
   ;; [cljs-http.client :as http]
   ;; [reagent.core :as r]
   ))

(defn main 
  ""
  []

  (js/console.log "hi from browser"))
```

This compiles to an expected 95,2 kB. Once I uncomment `[cljs-http.client :as http]` the total jumps to 299,7 kB; including `reagent` further raises it to 457,4 kB. **Since I'm not calling any functions from these namespaces, shouldn't the Google Closure compiler eliminate them as dead-code?**

The relevant parts of my shadow-cljs.edn are as follows: (omitting only three other builds, which, I might mention, do use the libs that are commented out):

```
 {:source-paths [;; "env/prod"
                 "src/server" "test" "src/browser" "src/common" "src/plibs" "target/classes"] 
 :dependencies [[reagent "0.9.1"]
                [bidi "2.1.6"]
                [com.taoensso/timbre "4.10.0"]
                ;; [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.520"]
                [macchiato/hiccups "0.4.1"]
                [macchiato/core "0.2.16"]
                [macchiato/env "0.0.6"]
                [mount "0.1.16"]

                ;; [cljs-ajax "0.8.0"]
                [cljs-http "0.1.46"]
                [hickory "0.7.1"]
                ;; [markdown-to-hiccup "0.6.2"]
                ]


 ;; :dev-http {3001 "public"}
 :builds {
          :spa-prod
          {
           :target :browser
           :output-dir "public/js/compiled"
           :asset-path "/js/compiled"
           :modules {:app-comp {:init-fn shadowman.app/main}}
           :compiler-options
           {:optimizations :advanced
            }}
          }}
```

I get the numbers above by running `shadow-cljs release spa-prod`. Unless I'm mistaken about what to expect from dead-code elimination something is wrong with this picture. If so I'll be grateful for any ideas on how to investigate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a [build report](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_build_report) to find out what your final build includes.

shadow-cljs and the Closure Compiler do not perform DCE for npm dependencies that were required by your build. Once they are included only basic DCE is done (ie. `:simple`) which is not capable of fully eliminating code. This is done because `:advanced` breaks too many npm dependencies. So in the case of `reagent` it'll end up including `react` and `react-dom` by default which won't be eliminated even if `reagent` is.

This is not limited to npm dependencies however. Not all CLJS code or even Closure Library code can be fully eliminated. Some code patterns just prevent DCE from ever kicking in. One example would be any `defmulti/defmethod` which can't be removed.

Comment: Many thanks! At least now I know what can and can't be done.